# How to get day of year, week of year from a DateTime Dart object

Tags: datetime, dart

I need to get day of year (day1 is 1rst of january), week of year, and month of year from a dart DateTime object.

I did not find any available library for this. Any idea ?

Answer (score 48):

[ORIGINAL ANSWER - Please scroll below to the updated answer, which has an updated calculation]

Week of year:

```
/// Calculates week number from a date as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation
int weekNumber(DateTime date) {
  int dayOfYear = int.parse(DateFormat("D").format(date));
  return ((dayOfYear - date.weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
}
```

The rest is available through [DateFormat](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) (part of the [intl package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl)).

[UPDATED ANSWER]
As pointed out by Henrik Kirk in a comment, the original answer did not include the necessary correction for certain dates. Here is a full implementation of the ISO week date calculation.

```
/// Calculates number of weeks for a given year as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year
int numOfWeeks(int year) {
  DateTime dec28 = DateTime(year, 12, 28);
  int dayOfDec28 = int.parse(DateFormat("D").format(dec28));
  return ((dayOfDec28 - dec28.weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
}

/// Calculates week number from a date as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation
int weekNumber(DateTime date) {
  int dayOfYear = int.parse(DateFormat("D").format(date));
  int woy =  ((dayOfYear - date.weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
  if (woy < 1) {
    woy = numOfWeeks(date.year - 1);
  } else if (woy > numOfWeeks(date.year)) {
    woy = 1;
  }
  return woy;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: This is a great answer. Must import `intl: ^0.15.7` as a dependency in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: This is only half of the calculation, if result is 0, you should get last week of previous year. See formula in link above.

Comment: Just a note: This will fail in some languages. For example Persian's value cannot be parsed as an integer.

Comment: @HenrikKirk absolutely true, I missed that. Well better late than never, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Day of year

```
final date = someDate;
final diff = now.difference(new DateTime(date.year, 1, 1, 0, 0));
final diffInDays = diff.inDays;
```

Week of year

```
final date = someDate;
final startOfYear = new DateTime(date.year, 1, 1, 0, 0);
final firstMonday = startOfYear.weekday;
final daysInFirstWeek = 8 - firstMonday;
final diff = date.difference(startOfYear);
var weeks = ((diff.inDays - daysInFirstWeek) / 7).ceil();
// It might differ how you want to treat the first week
if(daysInFirstWeek > 3) {
  weeks += 1;
}
```

Month of year

```
final monthOfYear = new DateTime.now().month;
```

Caution: That's not battle-tested code.

Comment: If he's considering YYYY-01-01 to be "day 1" then you'll need to add 1 to the difference, otherwise it will be off.

Comment: Also, since date differences are based on hours, there can be some issues due to DST when working with local time.

Comment: Local time is a good hint. Thanks @Herohtar. Using `someDate().toUtc()` should avoid such issues.

Comment: I think your week of year function does not correctly for dates like 2019-12-31, which is actually in the first calendar week of 2020 (in ISO 8601). I pasted my implementation below which works in these edge cases

Comment: "Day of year" function returns incorrect result! Converting to UTC does not help.

Answer (score 15):

Try this really simple dart package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). The code below will help

To get date day of year

```
// This will return the day of year from now
Jiffy.now().dayOfYear; // 295

// You can also pass in a dateTime object
Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(DateTime(2019, 1, 3)).dayOfYear; // 3
```

To get week of year

```
Jiffy.now().week; // 43

// You can also pass in an Array or Map
Jiffy.parseFromList([2019, 1, 3]).week; // 1
```

To get month of year

```
Jiffy.now().month; // 10

Jiffy.parseFromMap({
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 1,
    "day": 3
  }).month; // 1
```

Hope this answer helps

Comment: does your library keeps track of leaps years or leap days?

Answer (score 8):

## Number Week according to ISO 8601

```
int isoWeekNumber(DateTime date) {
    int daysToAdd = DateTime.thursday - date.weekday;
    DateTime thursdayDate = daysToAdd > 0 ? date.add(Duration(days: daysToAdd)) : date.subtract(Duration(days: daysToAdd.abs()));
    int dayOfYearThursday = dayOfYear(thursdayDate);
    return 1 + ((dayOfYearThursday - 1) / 7).floor();
}
int dayOfYear(DateTime date) {
    return date.difference(DateTime(date.year, 1, 1)).inDays;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for getting the week number.

Comment: Absolutely perfect 

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for DateTime(2025, 6, 1)

Answer (score 7):

This is my implementation of ISO 8601 Week of Year in Dart:

```
int getWeekOfYear(DateTime date) {
  final weekYearStartDate = getWeekYearStartDateForDate(date);
  final dayDiff = date.difference(weekYearStartDate).inDays;
  return ((dayDiff + 1) / 7).ceil();
}

DateTime getWeekYearStartDateForDate(DateTime date) {
  int weekYear = getWeekYear(date);
  return getWeekYearStartDate(weekYear);
}

int getWeekYear(DateTime date) {
  assert(date.isUtc);

  final weekYearStartDate = getWeekYearStartDate(date.year);

  // in previous week year?
  if(weekYearStartDate.isAfter(date)) {
    return date.year - 1;
  }

  // in next week year?
  final nextWeekYearStartDate = getWeekYearStartDate(date.year + 1);
  if(isBeforeOrEqual(nextWeekYearStartDate, date)) {
    return date.year + 1;
  }

  return date.year;
}

DateTime getWeekYearStartDate(int year) {
  final firstDayOfYear = DateTime.utc(year, 1, 1);
  final dayOfWeek = firstDayOfYear.weekday;
  if(dayOfWeek <= DateTime.thursday) {
    return addDays(firstDayOfYear, 1 - dayOfWeek);
  }
  else {
    return addDays(firstDayOfYear, 8 - dayOfWeek);
  }
}
```

Note that the "week year" is not always the calendar year, it could also be the one before or after:

```
void printWeekOfYear(DateTime date) {
  print('week ${getWeekOfYear(date)} in year ${getWeekYear(date)}');
}

printWeekOfYear(DateTime.utc(2017, 1, 1));
// --> week 52 in year 2016

printWeekOfYear(DateTime.utc(2019, 12, 31));
// --> week 1 in year 2020
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. I added some piece of code for your missing functions `isBeforeOrEqual()` and `addDays()`. `if(date.isAfter(nextWeekYearStartDate)||Utils.isSameDay(date, nextWeekYearStartDate)){
     return date.year + 1;
    }` and  `if(dayOfWeek <= DateTime.thursday) { return firstDayOfYear.subtract(Duration(days: dayOfWeek-1)); 
    }
    else {
      return firstDayOfYear.add(Duration(days:8 - dayOfWeek ))
    }`

Answer (score 5):

Dart SDK2.8.4 and later: 
**day of the year** , with no packages:

```
void main(){
  final now = new DateTime.now();
  final todayInDays = now.difference(new DateTime(now.year,1,1,0,0)).inDays; //return 157
}
```

reference (official)> [inDays, from Dart Official documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Duration/inDays.html)

Comment: Add "+ 1" to todayInDays to get the no of days in a year, because if there are 10 days, the difference of 10 - 1 = 9th day, but today is 10th day.

Comment: The simplest way to find the no of day in a year

Answer (score 3):

I wrote another solution based on your answers, it seem to work fine, but please feel free to give me feedback if you see a problem:

```
class DateUtils {

  static int currentWeek() {
    return weekOfYear(DateTime.now());
  }

  static int weekOfYear(DateTime date) {
    DateTime monday = weekStart(date);
    DateTime first = weekYearStartDate(monday.year);

    int week = 1 + (monday.difference(first).inDays / 7).floor();

    if (week == 53 && DateTime(monday.year, 12, 31).weekday < 4)
      week = 1;

    return week;
  }

  static DateTime weekStart(DateTime date) {
    // This is ugly, but to avoid problems with daylight saving
    DateTime monday = DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day);
    monday = monday.subtract(Duration(days: monday.weekday - 1));

    return monday;
  }

  static DateTime weekEnd(DateTime date) {
    // This is ugly, but to avoid problems with daylight saving
    // Set the last microsecond to really be the end of the week
    DateTime sunday = DateTime.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day, 23, 59, 59, 999, 999999);
    sunday = sunday.add(Duration(days: 7 - sunday.weekday));

    return sunday;
  }

  static DateTime weekYearStartDate(int year) {
    final firstDayOfYear = DateTime.utc(year, 1, 1);
    final dayOfWeek = firstDayOfYear.weekday;

    return firstDayOfYear.add(Duration(days: (dayOfWeek <= DateTime.thursday ? 1 : 8) - dayOfWeek));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It's the only one giving the correct week number for the following dates: 2017-1-1 should be 52; 2017-1-2 should be 1' 2020- 12-28 should be 53

Answer (score 1):

```
getWeekOfYear(){
    DateTime _kita=DateTime.now();
    int d=DateTime.parse("${_kita.year}-01-01").millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    int t= _kita.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    double daydiff= (t- d)/(1000 * (3600 * 24));
    double week= daydiff/7;
    return(week.ceil());
}
```

Tested and working you do not need any package

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding my solution because I am not seeing any with a variable first day of the week.

```
//sunday = 0, monday = 1, ...
int getWeekNumber(DateTime date, int firstDay) {
  DateTime d = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

//Set to first day of the week since it is the same weeknumber
  int difference = (7 + d.weekday - firstDay) % 7;
  d = d.add(Duration(days: -difference));

  int dayOfYear = int.parse(DateFormat('D', 'en').format(d));
  int weken = (dayOfYear / 7).floor();

// add an extra week if 4 or more days are in this year.
  int daysBefore = (dayOfYear % 7) - 1;
  if (daysBefore >= 4) {
    weken += 1;
  }

//if the last 3 days of the year,it is the first week
  DateTime t = d.add(const Duration(days: 3));
  if (t.year > d.year) {
    return 1;
  }
  weken += 1;

  return weken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This calculation works for me.

```
int dayOfWeek({DateTime date}) {
  if (date == null)
    date = DateTime.now();

  int w = ((dayOfYear(date) - date.weekday + 10) / 7).floor();

  if (w == 0) {
    w = getYearsWeekCount(date.year-1);
  } else if (w == 53) {
    DateTime lastDay = DateTime(date.year, DateTime.december, 31);
    if (lastDay.weekday < DateTime.thursday) {
      w = 1;
    }
  }
  return w;
}

int getYearsWeekCount(int year) {
  DateTime lastDay = DateTime(year, DateTime.december, 31);
  int count = dayOfWeek(date: lastDay);
  if (count == 1)
    count = dayOfWeek(date: lastDay.subtract(Duration(days: 7)));
  return count;
}

int dayOfYear(DateTime date) {
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < date.month; i++) {
    total += getDayOfMonth(date.year, i);
  }
  total+=date.day;
  return total;
}

int getDayOfMonth(int year, int month) {
  final List<int> days = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  if (year % 4 == 0) days[DateTime.february]++;
  return days[month];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the previous most voted solution is not working, if the year changes. for example has December 2020 a 53. week and if i change to January 2021 the previous solution computed 0 and not 53.

so i wrote a DateTime extension to cover year change.

```
  int get weekNumber {
    if (weekday > DateTime.thursday) {
      int toSubstract = weekday - DateTime.thursday;
      DateTime thursday = subtract(Duration(days: toSubstract));

      if (thursday.year != year) {
        return thursday.weekNumber;
      }
    }

    int dayOfYear = int.parse(format('D'));
    return ((dayOfYear - weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer of @András Szepesházi but as DateTime extension

```
extension DateTimeExt on DateTime {
  /// Calculates week number from a date as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculation
  int get weekNumber {
    int dayOfYear = int.parse(DateFormat("D").format(this));
    int woy = ((dayOfYear - weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
    if (woy < 1) {
      woy = _numOfWeeks(year - 1);
    } else if (woy > _numOfWeeks(year)) {
      woy = 1;
    }
    return woy;
  }

  /// Calculates number of weeks for a given year as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year
  int _numOfWeeks(int year) {
    DateTime dec28 = DateTime(year, 12, 28);
    int dayOfDec28 = int.parse(DateFormat("D").format(dec28));
    return ((dayOfDec28 - dec28.weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  static int getWeekNumber(DateTime datetime) {
    var day1 = DateTime(datetime.year);
    DateTime firstMonday;
    switch (day1.weekday) {
      case 1: // mon
        firstMonday = day1;
        break;
      case 2: // tue
        firstMonday = day1.add(const Duration(days: 6));
        break;
      case 3: // wed
        firstMonday = day1.add(const Duration(days: 5));
        break;
      case 4: // thir
        firstMonday = day1.add(const Duration(days: 4));
        break;
      case 5: // fri
        firstMonday = day1.add(const Duration(days: 3));
        break;
      case 6: // sat
        firstMonday = day1.add(const Duration(days: 2));
        break;
      case 7: // sun
        firstMonday = day1.add(const Duration(days: 1));
        break;
      default:
        firstMonday = day1;
    }

    Duration sinceStartOfYear = datetime.diff(firstMonday);
    double weekNo = (sinceStartOfYear.inDays / 7);
    var no = weekNo.floor();

    return no + 1;
  }
```

My full tested method.

Answer (score 0):

I live in America and prefer my calendar to start on sunday, this mimics your windows or google calendar.  Also note most week counters end years on 53 however the 1st week of the next year should overlap these dates, every other answer I have tested here seems to return 0 for Jan 1 in certain years.

```
getWeekOfYear(DateTime myDate){    
DateTime janFirst = DateTime(myDate.year, 1, 1);
DateTime firstDayOfYear;

// Get the first weeks sunday
if (janFirst.weekday != DateTime.sunday) {
  firstDayOfYear = janFirst.add(Duration(days: -janFirst.weekday));
} else {
  firstDayOfYear = janFirst;
}

// Set first sunday to epock milli
int d=firstDayOfYear.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
print(janFirst);
int t= myDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
print(myDate);
double daydiff= (t- d)/(1000 * (3600 * 24));
print(t-d);
print(daydiff);
double week= (daydiff+1)/7;
return(week.ceil() == 0 ? 1: week.ceil()); //Fixes Jan 1 sometimes returning 0
}
print(getWeekOfYear(DateTime.parse('2023-12-30')));
```